# excel macro filter, delete and sort

Tags: vba, excel

I want a create a macro that filters,deletes & sorts values. 
Let there be 4 columns:

> 1. Serial No
> 2. Data
> 3. Amount
> 4. ID (Numeric)

The  macro should

1. delete all rows having amount=0.
2. Reassign serial no because now there are fewer rows than before.
3. Sort the data according to ID

Unable to proceed with creation. Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? [See this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a basic question, and it does not seem to need a universal solution, but rather 2 loops and then as sort call... Try looping (for or while) over the records to delete rows such as:

```
Sub macro1()
ColumnWithSerial = 1
ColumnWithID = 4
ColumnWithAmounts = 3
'loop over column with IDs
Dim i As Long, tempID As Long
i = 3      'variable to loop = set to 1st row with data (after header)
tempID = 1 'variable to update IDs
Do While Len(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, ColumnWithID).Value) > 0
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, ColumnWithSerial).Value = tempID
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, ColumnWithAmounts).Value = 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, ColumnWithAmounts).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        tempID = tempID + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
'now call sort method (easy to record and then adapt) (make sure to use sort and not filter)

End Sub
```

This should generally do the job, unless there is some parameter that needs specifying...

Comment: The code still does not work. Check [link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56797378/test%20macro.xlsm

Comment: You need to set i to the first row of your table... You should probably also comment out the row Sheets("SheetName").Cells(i,ColumnWithID).value = tempID as this shuold work on column 1 not column 4...

Comment: I have updated the code. it works now... just the sort is missing

Comment: thanks for the updation @ex-man , but the SNo do not get updated